# Unable to get product category

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I've created a custom product details page and am trying to get the category of that product but it's not working.

I have created a form where people will fill out questions like:

> What brand do you like?

Click next...

> What model do you like?

Click next and so on. It will grab products based on their filled information.

Here is my code

```
if ( isset( $_REQUEST['product_tag'] ) ) {
    $tags = $_REQUEST['product_tag'];
}

$args = array( 
    'post_type'      => 'product', 
    'posts_per_page' => 1, 
    'product_tag'    => $tags 
);
$loop           = new WP_Query( $args );
$product_count  = $loop->post_count;

if ( $product_count > 0 ) :
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) :
        $loop->the_post();
        global $product;        
        global $post;
        $thePostID = $post->post_title;
        //echo '<img src="'.$woocommerce->plugin_url().'/assets/images/placeholder.png" alt="" width="'.$woocommerce->get_image_size('shop_catalog_image_width').'px" height="'.$woocommerce->get_image_size('shop_catalog_image_height').'px" />';
        $terms = wp_get_object_terms($post->ID, 'product_cat'); 
        echo $terms->name;

        // ...
    endwhile;
endif;
```

Comment: Welcome to WPSE! Unfortunately, 3rd Party Plugins ( such as WooCommerce ) are considered to be [off-topic](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) here and would be better suited on the [WordPress forums](https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/woocommerce) or handled by their support. That being said - I think you may need to use a [Tax Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters) instead for `$tags`.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few things that are wrong.

- remove global variable as we are already working in a custom loop no need for global $post or other globals.
- Get all posts with that selected tag in the `$args` (assuming this is what you want).
- If you know the type of request, I'd use `$_GET` or `$_POST` accordingly instead of `$_REQUEST`.
- `$terms` is an object, so you need to iterate over it to get the info you want
- Here I hooked this example to `init` but you might want to hook later depending on your code.

.

```
add_action('init', 'wpse_233955' );
function wpse_233955 (){
  if ( isset( $_REQUEST['prod_tag'] ) ) {
    $tags = $_REQUEST['prod_tag'];
 }

 $args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'product',
    'posts_per_page' => -1, // Get all post with the tag not just 1
    'product_tag'    => $tags
  );

  $query           = new WP_Query( $args ); // $query is you custom loop
  $product_count   = $query->post_count;

  if ( $product_count > 0 ) :

    while ( $query->have_posts() ) :

      $query->the_post(); // This will set the $query object to the current post item
      $thePostID = get_the_ID(); 
      $terms = wp_get_object_terms( $thePostID, 'product_cat');

      foreach( $terms as $term ){
        echo $term->name;
      }

      // ...
    endwhile;
  endif;
}
```